# create button beside proceed to checkout button

Tags: magento-1.9

I am beginner in learning **Magento ver. 1.9**. I need to create custom button in checkout/cart page exactly beside of proceed to checkout button

How to do that?

I found solution regarding this question but can not find any exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml 
if u dont find this file here then it will be located in your base folder which is located at 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml

Add new button near the Procced to Checkout button.

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" 
    class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"
    <?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> 
    onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span>
    </button>
    <button>Add New Button Here</button>

<?php endif?>
```

Using Module:

using custom module add below conent in the config file

> `app/code/local/CustomCheckout/Checkout/etc/config.xml.`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <CustomCheckout_Checkout>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </CustomCheckout_Checkout>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                     <CustomCheckout_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">CustomCheckout_Checkout</CustomCheckout_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <checkout>
                <file>checkout.xml</file>
            </checkout>
        </updates>
    </layout>       
</frontend>
```

override the checkout.xml layout which in turn calls the said link.phtml file. Place the new layout file at following location

> app/design/frontend/default/CustomCheckout/layout/checkout.xml.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>checkout/onepage/link.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Place modified link.phtml file under

> app/design/frontend/default/CustomCheckout/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml

Comment: thank you so much but still i need to do this using overriding ,how to do that way?

Comment: overriding means by creating new module?

Comment: yes mam,i already created module but just need to set button beside of proceed to checkout

Comment: please find the modified answer